# I need to change the type of few columns in a pandas dataframe. Can't do so using iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, casting

In a dataframe with around 40+ columns I am trying to change dtype for first 27 columns from float to int by using iloc:

```
df1.iloc[:,0:27]=df1.iloc[:,0:27].astype('int')
```

However, it's not working. I'm not getting any error, but dtype is not changing as well. It still remains float.

**Now the strangest part:**

If I first change dtype for only 1st column (like below):

```
df1.iloc[:,0]=df1.iloc[:,0].astype('int')
```

and then run the earlier line of code:

```
df1.iloc[:,0:27]=df1.iloc[:,0:27].astype('int')
```

It works as required.
Any help to understand this and solution to same will be grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Which pandas version are you using? I am not able to reproduce the Problem. I can see the column type has been changed to int32. without changing the first column only

Comment: @Yash
python : 3.8.3
pandas : 1.0.5

Comment: @Rishik, I have pandas 1.0.3, could you try that? because i definitely don't have a problem there. I also made sure to read file as str so that it does not automatically convert. But no issues there

Comment: @YashShah ok, then I guess it has to do something with version I suppose then. Thanks  will check that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it is a bug in `1.0.5`. I tested on my `1.0.5`. I have the same issue as yours. The `.loc` also has the same issue, so I guess pandas devs break something in `iloc/loc`. You need to update to latest pandas or use a workaround. If you need a workaround, using assignment as follows

```
df1[df1.columns[0:27]] = df1.iloc[:, 0:27].astype('int')
```

I tested it. Above way overcomes this bug. It will turn first 27 columns to dtype `int32`

Comment: Are you sure a newer version of Pandas changed the behaviour back? I'm using 1.4.3 and it's still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use iloc. You can just create a loop over the 27 columns and convert them into the data type that you want.

```
df.info()
my_columns = df.columns.to_list()[0:27]
for i in my_columns:
   df[i] = df[i].astype('int32')
df.info()
```